# Python Requests: How can I properly submit a multipart/form POST using a file name

Tags: python-2.7, curl, python-requests

I have taken a look at other questions related to multipart/form POST requests in Python but unfortunately, they don't seem to address my exact question. Basically, I normally use CURL in order to hit an API service that allows me to upload zip files in order to create HTML5 assets. The CURL command I use looks like this:

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: api: 222111" --form "type=html" --form "file=Folder1/Folder2/example.zip" "https://example.api.com/upload?ins_id=123"

I am trying to use a python script to iterate through a folder of zip files in order to upload all of these files and receive a "media ID" back. This is what my script looks like:

```
import os
import requests
import json


ins_id = raw_input("Please enter your member ID: ")
auth = raw_input("Please enter your API authorization token: ")

for filename in os.listdir("zips"):
    if filename.endswith(".zip"):
        file_path = os.path.abspath(filename)
        url = "https://example.api.com/upload?
        ins_id="+str(ins_id)
        header = {"Authorization": auth}
        response = requests.post(url, headers=header, files={"form_type": 
        (None, "html"), "form_file_upload": (None, str(file_path))})
        api_response = response.json() 
        print api_response
```

This API service requires the file path to be included when submitting the POST. However, when I use this script, the response indicates that "file not provided". Am I including this information correctly in my script?

Thanks.

Update:

I think I am heading in the right direction now (thanks to the answer provided) but now, I receive an error message stating that there is "no such file or directory". My thinking is that I am not using os.path correctly but even if I change my code to use "relpath" I still get the same message. My script is in a folder and I have a completely different folder called "zips" (in the same directory) which is where all of my zip files are stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To upload files with the `request` library, you can include the file handler directly in the JSON as described in the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). This is the corresponding example that I have taken from there:

```
url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
files = {'file': open('path_to_your_file', 'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

If we integrate this in your script, it would look as follows (I also made it slightly more *pythonic*):

```
import os
import requests
import json


folder = 'zips'
ins_id = raw_input("Please enter your member ID: ")
auth = raw_input("Please enter your API authorization token: ")
url = "https://example.api.com/upload?"
header = {"Authorization": auth}

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if not filename.endswith(".zip"):
        continue

    file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(folder, filename))
    ins_id="+str(ins_id)"
    response = requests.post(
        url, headers=header, 
        files={"form_type": (None, "html"), 
        "form_file_upload": open(file_path, 'rb')}
    )
    api_response = response.json() 
    print api_response
```

As I don't have the API end point, I can't actually test this code block - but it should be something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be going in the right direction now but I think I may be using os.path incorrectly since I now receive an error message back stating that there is no such file or directory. I will include my updates in my original post, thanks.

Comment: The problem is the path to the file - it needs to include the folder. I updated the answer.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks!