# How to pass image to requests.post in python?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

Sorry Guys, I am new to Django, I am stuck with images upload.

I have a REST_API for image upload. I pass the image and inside API get that image by using 
`request.FILES['fileToUpload']`.

Now I have an external API, which uploads an image on my behalf, that API is working fine on the postman.

Here is the path of that API.

http://164.68.110.65/file_load.php

But in Django. I am not able to pass the image to this API. I have tried many ways.

like these.

```
 image = request.FILES['fileToUpload']
 temp = Image.open(image)
 byte_io = BytesIO()
 temp.save(byte_io, 'png')
 files = {'fileToUpload': byte_io.getvalue() }
 response = requests.post( self.URL, files=files)
 print(response.status_code, response.content, response.reason)
```

but it always giving me an error that image format is not matched.

can you please tell me, in python-requests, how we should pass images or files that are got my `request.FILES['file_name_any']`.

Thanks.
I will be very thankful for your favor.

Comment: I think you have to base64 encode the image before sending it

Comment: This answer might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628257/3628578

Comment: Is there no other way in which i can send images? Like form data type anything.?

Comment: how about `with image.open('rb') as f: files = {'fileToUpload': f}; response = requests.post(self.URL, files=files)`

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten its working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `image` is an `UploadedFile` or a `TemporaryUploadedFile` which is a subclass of `File`. So you can just `.open()` it normally as any other `File` object:

```
with image.open('rb') as f:
    files = {'fileToUpload': f}
response = requests.post(self.URL, files=files)
```

No need to take the detour through saving the file first.