# Trying to call an API with an image but keeps getting ValueError

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have been following the advice given on this thread: [How to pass image to requests.post in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57594348/how-to-pass-image-to-requests-post-in-python)

However, I got stuck with the error, "ValueError: read of closed file".

I have been trying to invoke an API that does some image recognition. At the moment, I am using Postman's form-data feature to send it to the Django server, which then uses "requests" to invoke the API. Let me show you the code snippet.

```
def post(self, request):

    img = request.FILES["file"]
    with img.open("rb") as f:
        files = {"fileToUpload": f}
    url = "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getSimilarProducts?APIKEY=XXXXXXX"
    response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

After sending the request, when I check each variable with the debugger, the 'img' variable contains a temporary uploaded file like so:

```
<TemporaryUploadedFile: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.png (image/png)>
```

What am I missing? And what should I do to overcome this error? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response should be within the ***`with` context***

```
def post(self, request):
    img = request.FILES['file']
    with img.open('rb') as f:
        files = {'fileToUpload': f}
        url = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/getSimilarProducts?APIKEY=XXXXXXX'
        response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```